# For Task Pause and Resume Can I use ManualResetEventSlim?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using this code for task resume and pause. I need to pause because doSomething(); method will not work every time for example when data came from web api. So CPU will not tire.I am using this at a lot of project.But I'm not sure this is reliable or best way.Can I ask your ideas?

```
 static ManualResetEventSlim mre = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        mre.Set();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                mre.Wait();
                doSomething();
            }

        });

        mre.Reset();
        Console.WriteLine("Task Paused");
        Console.WriteLine("Task Will Resume After 1 Second");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);//To simulate, waiting data from Web Api etc.  for doSomething(); 
        mre.Set();

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: This is a code review question and you should ask it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you have race condition between `mre.Wait()` and `mre.Reset()` after `mre.Set()`. It is possible that mre.Wait() could execute faster than resetting the signal and therefore your `doSomething()` method fires before first Thread.Sleep(). You could easily simulate it if you add Thread.Sleep(10) just before mre.Reset();

Comment: If you think you need to "pause" a task, you are doing something wrong. In this case, you are treating a Task as if it were a thread. It's not. You *don't* need that infinite loop. There are other ways to execute tasks that don't require wasting a thread to do nothing

Comment: What is your *actual* problem? Why do you think you need to pause tasks, instead of simply *issuing* tasks only when there is work to do? You mention waiting for data from Web API - why aren't you using `async/await` to avoid blocking? What is `doSomething` supposed to do?

Comment: You should have a look at DataFlow pipelines, maybe that is what you are really looking for

Comment: waiting for data from Web API is just an example , That is what I mean data can be from another thread ,task,web api or data input etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                _semaphore.Wait();
                doSomething();
            }

        });

        _semaphore.Release();
        Console.WriteLine("Task Paused");
        Console.WriteLine("Task Will Resume After 1 Second");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);//To simulate, waiting data from Web Api etc.  for doSomething();    
         _semaphore.Release();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Semaphore will always transition into the
kernel; in contrast, as with ManualResetEventSlim, SemaphoreSlim has been designed to stay in user-mode as
much as possible, typically resulting in better performance and scalability for intra-process thread communication.
 SemaphoreSlim also
provides a **CurrentCount** property which gives access to that count value, typically used only for debugging
purposes.

**Considerations:**

As with ManualResetEventSlim, accessing SemaphoreSlim’s AvailableWaitHandle property forces initialization of
an underlying kernel object. This adds overhead to subsequent Wait and Release invocations, which now need to
maintain the state of that WaitHandle.

Note that the name of this property, AvailableWaitHandle, differs from the name of the WaitHandle property on
ManualResetEventSlim. This is due to a functional difference in the returned WaitHandle. Waiting on a
ManualResetEvent or a ManualResetEventSlim does not change the signaled status of the event. However,
waiting on a semaphore may mutate the semaphore, as it can decrease the semaphore’s internal count. As such,
the AvailableWaitHandle property returns a WaitHandle that merely indicates a high likelihood that there is count
available for consumption in the SemaphoreSlim; to actually obtain access to the associated shared resource,
however, one must wait on the SemaphoreSlim directly.

This all means that certain synchronization operations possible with Semaphore are not possible with
SemaphoreSlim. For example, with Semaphore it is possible to use WaitHandle.WaitAll to atomically acquire
resources from multiple semaphores; that functionality does not exist with SemaphoreSlim.

Comment: _semaphore.Release() will be called whenever true is false => I guess that will never happen

Comment: And the question is about pausing the task execution and not pausing the main execution

Comment: The task will not pause when you call release before. SemaphoreSlim is not the right tool for controlling that